# Substituting numbers for parameters

Tags: calculus, limits

In mathematical and scientific modelling one often works with parameters. Parameters can be considered constants, for which the value has not been specified. After each step in the mathematical evaluation of the model one may choose to replace an unspecified parameter by a certain value.

For example, if I have a model with one variable $x$ and two parameters $A$ and $B$, I may substitute at some stage the value $A = 0$ or $B = 0$, and then continue with my calculation. This should yield the same result as when I complete the calculation with both parameters $A$ and $B$ unspecified, and only at the very end make my substitution.

However, this practice does not always lead to the correct result. A simple example is when the full model calculation results in:

$$x = arctan(A/B)$$

This expression is correct for all values of $A$ and $B$. Hence I can take the limit of $A$ and $B$ to zero, and this works fine as long as I am precise about their ratio $A/B$. On the other hand, had I fixed the value of $A$ at zero early in the calculation, I would have ended up with $x = 0$. Had I set $B$ equal to zero, the result would be $x = \pi/2$.

What we see here is that our model, after having set one parameter equal to zero early on, is blind to the fact that the remaining parameter might be of comparable magnitude as the first one. That may be unfortunate, but that is how mathematics works.

Is this regarded as a problem? Is there a cure for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What you are really confused about here is multivariable limits. You have the expression $x= \arctan(A/B)$. This of this as a two variable function: $x(A,B)= \arctan(A/B)$. Your issue is that $\lim_{(A,B) \to (0,0)} \arctan(A/B)$ does not exist. An easy way of showing this is
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{B \to 0} \lim_{A \to 0} \arctan(A/B)&= \lim_{B \to 0} 0= 0 \\
\lim_{A \to 0} \lim_{B \to 0^+} \arctan(A/B)&= \lim_{A \to 0} \arctan(\infty)= \dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{split}
$$
Therefore, the limit does not exist. What the issue is here that $B=0$ is not in the domain of $\arctan(A/B)$ because $A/B$ is not defined when $A \neq 0$ and $B=0$. What we mean we set set $B=0$ for arctan is we define $A/0= \infty$ when $A>0$ and $A/0= -\infty$ when $A<0$ and we define $\arctan(\infty)= \pi/2$ and $\arctan(-\infty)= -\pi/2$.

Notice this is a definition. You could have defined $\arctan(\infty)=\arctan(-\infty)=0$ if you had wanted. But there is a reason we define arctan at $\pm \infty$ the way we do --- so that it aligns with $\lim_{y \to \pm\infty} \arctan y$ because we want $\arctan y$ to be continuous. There are other explanations about what the problem is and why we define arctan in this way but this one should be fairly 'self-intuitive.'

Answer (score 0):

This is a false problem.

When you write expressions, they have a domain of validity. For instance, the function

$$\dfrac AB$$

excludes $B=0$ (and so does $\arctan\dfrac AB$*). Contrary to your belief, "this expression is correct for all values of A and B" is false. So any discussion you can make around this function is made under the implicit condition $B\ne0$.

---

*You might oppose that it is "well-known" that $\arctan\dfrac10$ is $\dfrac\pi2$, but in fact that would be referring to a different function, say $\arctan_2(A,B)$, with a proper definition when $B=0$. Anyway, even this function is undefined with $A=B=0$.

---

This even goes farther than you think. Assume you develop some argument around the ratio

$$R:=\frac AB$$ and later in the discussion consider the product

$$BR.$$

Then if $B$ is known to be $0$, it is not "legal" to draw any conclusion by replacing $BR$ by $A$.

Comment: The problem is real enough. Take $f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)^2$ and integrate over the rectangle: $x$ from $A$ to $1$ and $y$ from $B$ to $1$. The issue I described is at the heart of why the integrals over $x$ and $y$ do not commute when $A$ and $B$ go to zero. .

Comment: @M.Wind: I am afraid that you missed my answer. Think out of your box.